# Laravel model inheritance - how to call a function from parent model?

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel 5.2 app, there is the following model hierarchy:

```
//Model.php:
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
abstract class MyModel extends Model {
    public function getAllColumnsNames() {
        ...
    }

//Article.php
namespace App\Models;
class Article extends MyModel {
    ...
}
```

Then in the controller, there is a function which gets $item as parameter and $item is of type App\Models\Article:

```
//MyController.php
use App\Models\MyModel;
...
    public function japi ($item) {
        if (! $item instanceof MyModel) {
            return [];
        } else {
            $columns = $item->getAllColumnNames();
        }
    }
```

The last line throws an exception:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAllColumnNames()
```

I expected that this function will be inherited from MyModel class but in fact it's called from Builder class.

How to call the function from MyModel in the controller?

[Edit]
Actually, even if I move the getAllColumnNames() function from MyModel directly to Articles class, the same exception is thrown. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the method name. You define the method as `getAllColumnsNames` and when you try to access it you call `getAllColumnNames` (notice that `Column` is singular). It should be:

```
$columns = $item->getAllColumnsNames();
```

The Laravel Eloquent model uses the [`__call`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3551) magic method to delegate any methods that are undefined to the Query Builder. That's why you can use `Article::find(1);` even if the `find` method is defined by the [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L139-L155) class and not the model, and that's why you get the exception for the `Builder` class and not the `Article` class.